# LINQ - Selecting the count of rows where a column begins with "ABCD"

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table "Orders" with a column "OrderNumber". How do I select the count of rows where OrderNumber's first four chars equals a certain char sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I select the count of rows

Use [Enumerable.Count Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx)

> where OrderNumber's first four chars equals a certain char sequence?

Use [String.StartsWith Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx)

```
var resultCount = yourContext.Orders.Count(r=> r.OrderNumber.StartsWith("ABCD"));
```